# How do I express the following sentence in valid owl syntax?

Tags: rdf, owl, ontology, rdfs

All math courses are taught by David only (no other lecturer must be involved).`

```
<owl:Class rdf:ID="Math">
<owl:Restriction>
<owl:onProperty uni:Resource="#isTaughtBy"/>
<owl:allValuesFrom uni:Resource="#9432"/>
</owl:Restriction>
</owl:Class>
```

the above code seems invalid why i try to draw the graph please help.
If anyone is wondering about the #9432 it refers to David

Comment: Have you tried to produce any examples yourself?

Comment: You want the axiom **MathClass ⊑ ∀isTaughtBy.{David} ⊓ ∃.isTaughtBy.{David}**.

Answer (score 0):

```
<owl:Class rdf:ID="Math">
<rdfs:subClassOf>
    <owl:Restriction>
        <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="#isTaughtBy"/>
        <owl:hasValue>
            <owl:Class>
                <uni:Name>david</uni:Name>
            </owl:Class>
        </owl:hasValue‌​>
    </owl:Restriction>
</rdfs:subClassOf>
```

[graph produced by rdf validator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mFSO.png)

Comment: I don't think that this is right.  This says that every instance of the class Math is related by the property isTaughtBy to _.  I don't think that `<owl:Class><uni:Name>david</uni:Name></owl:Class>` is correct.    And even if it is, it would say that the course is taught by an David, but not that it's *not* taught by anyone else.  A course could still be taught by multiple lecturers

Comment: In protégé it would be **MathClass SubClassOf (isTaughtBy only {David}) and (isTaughtBy some {David})**. I'd suggest that you use protégé or another OWL based tool,or at least a humans readable rdf syntax,  rather than ttying to write the rdf/xml serialization of an rdf graph mapping of an owl ontology.  It will probably be a much more pleasant experience.